# Reference service for a cache

Tags: java, cache, optional

I'm using JDK 11.

This is my code:

```
public class ReferenceService {

    private final transient Cache<String, Reference> cache;
    private final transient EntityManager entityManager;

    public ReferenceService(
        Cache<String,Reference> cache,
        EntityManager entityManager
    ) {
        this.cache = cache;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }


    public Optional<Reference> get(String id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.cache.get(id))
            .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(this.entityManager.find(Reference.class, id)));
    }
}
```

I would like to know to write this code again in order to it's more elegant:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(this.cache.get(id))
    .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(this.entityManager.find(Reference.class, id)));
```

I guess I'm using too much `Optional.ofNullable` each time I need to get a reference from cache or from persistence layer.

**ADITIONAL CODE**

```
private <T> Cache<String, T> getOrCreateCache(String name, Class<T> type) {
    Cache<String, T> cache = cacheManager.getCache(name, String.class, type);

    if (cache == null) {
        CompleteConfiguration<String, T> config =
            new MutableConfiguration<String, T>()
                .setTypes(String.class, type);

        cache = cacheManager.createCache(name, config);
    }

    return cache;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer now. I hope that answers your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Design Fix

The correct solution to this is to make your **cache** responsible for retrieving the entity on cache-miss.

Consider for a moment the goals of a cache:

- Keep expensive to calculate / retrieve information in a manner suitable to quick access
- Abstract away cache handling (invalidation, cache-misses, ...) from consumers
- Give certain guarantees for the consistency of cached information

As it stands the way this code is setting up and using the cache utterly fails on the second point. Luckily `javax.caching.Cache` does support loading entries into the cache on misses using a `CacheLoader`.

For this to happen you need to create a CacheLoader that is aware of the EntityManager used to access the entities:

```
[..] config = new MutableConfiguration<String, T>()
  .setTypes(String.class, type)
  .setReadThrough(true) // enables silent loading
  .setCacheLoaderFactory(new FactoryBuilder.SingletonFactory(
    new CacheLoader<String, T>() {
      @Override
      public T load(String key) {
          return entityManager.find(type, key);
      }
      @Override
      public Map<String, T> loadAll(Iterable<? extends String> keys) {
          return Stream.of(keys)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::load));
      }
   });
```

You should notice at this point that you're locking yourself into caching on a single primary key (namely `String`). This is something that might bite you in the backside down the road, but if you only use Strings as primary keys for entities that should be alright.

n.b. that I haven't even checked whether this code compiles.

Comment: Could I ask you for giving some lights me about why it's a better practice a `ClassLoader` is aware of handling the `entityManager` or whatever data-access layer?
I mean, my straightforward first approach was to try to get the entity from cache, and at the same method on service layer, try to get it using the entity manager.
I guess, it's better to use a `ClassLoader` approach instead of, but I don't quite figure out how come.

Comment: Not `ClassLoader`, `CacheLoader`. It's better practice, because it makes sure the Cache is filled correctly. It also allows you to build on the abstraction that a Cache exposes to you. That way your code doesn't need to care about the peculiarities of the cache mechanic.

Comment: I'm struggling with an issue related with this behavior. Guess on a `create(dto)`, shere `dto` has no an `id` field. So, when I call the `cache.putIfAbsent(key??, dto)`, with `key` hould I use if it's not resolved until it's written on db. I hope I've explained so well.

Comment: Creating an entry in you database should not affect the cache in any way. That's not the job of the cache. The cache is a tool to avoid roundtripping to the database on repeated reads. A write to the database is usually only reflected in the cache upon a subsequent read request. For that request, you will need to have the key in the first place. So the question as I understood it shouldn't pose itself

Comment: Could take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633892/jcache-write-through-without-key)?